# Compiling C with Objective-C and duplicate symbol linker error (iPhone related)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode, ios4

I have the following file testf.h:

```
#ifndef TESTF_H_
#define TESTF_H_
int test(int what){
    return what;
}
#endif
```

I included/imported it in TestAppDelegate.h (which is used for other .m files in my xcode project). I get a duplicate symbol error. If I included/imported testf.h in a .m file that is never included/imported in other files then it works fine. So it seems like the `#ifndef/#define/#endif` has no effect. Is there anyway to go around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a function definition, it belongs in a c, cpp or m file.

This popular trick with #defines will protect you from compiler errors (typically to survive circular #include dependencies. ) It will not protect against a linker error. This is exactly why people put declarations in h files and definitions in c (or m) files.

Comment: Moved my definitions to the c file and kept the h strictly for declarations. Worked. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 4):

Including function definitions (as opposed to declarations) in header files is generally a bad idea and now you know why. You want two separate files, the header would look like this:

```
#ifndef TESTF_H_
#define TESTF_H_
extern int test(int);
#endif
```

And then a `.c` file (or possibly a `.m` file if you want to use Objective-C rather than plain C) like this:

```
int test(int what) {
    return what;
}
```

The header file will let the compiler know what `test` is, what it returns, and what arguments it should take; that's enough information for the compiler to arrange a call to `test`; that's actually more information than the compiler needs but some of us like our compilers to do some error checking. The C source file will (after being compiled into a object file) let the linker know what code the `test` symbol resolves to.

Right now you're ending up with multiple globally visible instances of the `test` symbol, one for every file that has included your `testf.h`.

Answer (score 1):

The other option, for a simple function, is to declare it `inline`:

```
inline int cNorm(float _amp) {
  return 42;
}
```